# How to specify the Event Log Source where ASP.NET writes unhandled exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, iis, event-log

By default ASP.NET writes any unhandled exception to the default `ASP.NET X.Y.Z.0` event log source. Is it possible to specify either configuration that the events and exceptions for a particular application has to be logged in a specific event log Source?

The reason is that I would want all issues directly related to my application to be stored in a separate event log category that can then be filtered against.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but could you use the [Global.Application_Error() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255098%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) and use syntax like this within it:

```
   Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

   //log to Event Log
   EventLog.WriteEntry("Whatever",
     "MESSAGE: " + ex.Message + 
     "\nSOURCE: " + ex.Source +
     "\nFORM: " + Request.Form.ToString() + 
     "\nQUERYSTRING: " + Request.QueryString.ToString() +
     "\nTARGETSITE: " + ex.TargetSite +
     "\nSTACKTRACE: " + ex.StackTrace, 
     EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

Comment: this is how I can create my own event source to log events from code. The problem I have is that I need to log exceptions that ASP.NET logs itself (for example, errors like `web.config cannot be parsed`).

Comment: @Knaģis ah ok. I have changed my answer now in the hope that it might help, but I've never done this before so I'm kind of guessing :)

Comment: the new sample does not work for the case when the error occurs when initializing the application (like the mentioned config parsing) and potentially other low levels errors.

Comment: @Knaģis OK, I give up. Does it work ok for other unhandled exceptions?

Comment: @Knaģis what you're trying to achieve sounds to me like something you'd need to configure in IIS.